# Ajax is not defined error in a Ruby on Rails app

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

In Ruby on Rails app one JS function which is using Ajax, it is giving me on the console this error: `Uncaught ReferenceError: ajax is not defined`
I have more functions in the same JS file which are not giving the same error and are working good. Would like to understand what wrong with this function.

My code:

```
SveCrf.prototype.getForms = function(forms) {
    var _this = this;
    return Promise.all(forms.map(function(form, idx) {
        _this.html.push(_this.placeholder(idx, form.label)); // Create the slot for the result.
        return ajax({
            url: "/mdrs/form_show",
            data: {"id": form.form_id, "namespace": form.form_namespace},
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'html'
        }).then(function(result) {
            return result
        }).catch(handleAjaxError)
    }))
}
```

Comment: As the error says what is wrong is that function `ajax()` is not defined. Where do you define this function?

Comment: @JordiNebot the function is related to this code: https://pastebin.com/SDpMDnpr 

Line 51 is called

Comment: The code in this pastebin does **not** define any function called `ajax`. But it uses jQuery's ajax function. Maybe you're just missing the `$`? `return $.ajax({...`

Comment: Yes I did that but now I have an other error:
`Uncaught TypeError: $.ajax(...).then(...).catch is not a function`

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Running Bundle show I have this `jquery-rails (4.0.4)`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161513/discussion-between-jakub-and-jordi-nebot).

Comment: @Jakub, did you include the jquery library?